# Checkout an SVN Project using Subversive in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive, svn-checkout

So I'm able to pull the files out of the svn but I'm unable to get Eclipse to understand these files are part of an SVN.

I have TortoiseSVN install on the system as well, and I'm wondering if that is causing an issue?

Base question, how can I using Eclipse and Subversive checkout a project from my SVN repo?

Comment: We use subclipse, and I find it a little bit better than subversive.

I have found that both eclipse svn plugins tend to have problems with files that have been touched by Tortoise.  It's best not to use both on the same fileset. However, just having TortoiseSVN on your machine should not cause any bad interactions by itself.

Comment: Now if I can get my boss to switch over from Subversive...

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166220/restore-eclipse-subversion-project-connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).  Its excellent and you can install it directly from eclipse using the appropriate update site. I prefer it to the subversive plugin and TortoiseSVN.

Comment: The subversive plugin used to be the way to go, but the subclipse plugin is now the better one in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, we are switching the office over now.

Comment: Nice! You will be happy you did.

Comment: Seconds after the install, it was better than subversive.

Answer (score 0):

Either: File > New > Project > SVN > Project from SVN

Or (I like this one better): Go to the "SVN Repository Exploring" View > right click on your project's folder (trunk, for example) > Check Out (or Find/Check Out As...)