# Eclipse lost svn references for every project in workspace after forced close

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a workspace with several projects connected to svn repositories via subclipse plugin. During a system restart, it seems eclipse was forcedly closed, and now I have restarted it, it seems the references to svn are lost. They are not disconnected, as there're interrogation signs as if every file was recently added, and .svn folders are still there. Also, the brackets that usually show the path in the repository are empty.

[image]

I could checkout the projects again and manually copy my last changes, but that's really annoying as there are about 10 projects.

Anyone experienced a similar issue and found a quick solution?

Comment: Have you run `svn cleanup` and/or `svn update`?

Comment: Just tried, but the options are disabled in the Team context menu in eclipse.

Comment: Then do it from the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I tried as well but didn't work neither. I get this error 'The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this'. Not sure is this is related with the issue, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened again today, and I fixed it by doing a `Team->Refresh/Cleanup` on the project. Can't believe I didn't try this before!

Comment: Could you please point where to find this option in eclipse ? when the repo is not sync anymore the team menu option doesn't provide the Refresh option in Keppler

Comment: @EmmanuelBrunet The option was there in my case, maybe your problem is slightly different. I was working on `adt` with eclipse version `4.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

You subversion Eclipse plugin does not support svn 1.7. That happened to me too, when i upgraded the Tortoise shell integration and tried to commit the same project from Eclipse. The latest Subversive client plugin can be downloaded here: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php) / [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=2D509C47CB298CD69DED37B15487C3D1?pageID=p4wYuA)

Comment: Actually, I'm using subversion plugin, not subversive.

Comment: Thats just the name of the implementation. I think it should be "Subversive" or "Subclipse". In Eclipse click Help -> About and find out the right name. Both are subversion plugins.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I'm wondering if there's a solution that don't involve uninstalling subclipse plugin and installing subversive.

Comment: You can also update Subclipse to version 1.8. Just find out witch on is the one you already installed and add the new update site in Eclipse.

Comment: Subclipse supports every Subversion version possible. You just need to install the right version of Subclipse.  http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA  I would assume you upgraded to Subversion 1.8 and therefore need Subclipse 1.10.x which has support for that version.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today and "Team -> Share project" was enough.

Found it here: [Restore Eclipse subversion project connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166220/restore-eclipse-subversion-project-connection)